# CSS showing up in Eclipse PDT tooltips

Tags: 11.04, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix unreadable tooltips in Eclipse Helios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1620/how-to-fix-unreadable-tooltips-in-eclipse-helios)

I am still mostly a novice in Ubuntu and have never used Eclipse until today. I downloaded the Zend PDT Eclipse IDE and everything seems to be working pretty well, apart from the tooltips. (see image below). It would appear that some CSS is appearing before the tooltip text and hitting tab does not complete the code, as I suspect it is meant to do.

[image]

I have looked all over for a solution but all I can find are posts regarding the tooltips being black, not the case here. Any ideas?

When I tried to run from the command line, I got this error:
(Eclipse:8920): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.

Comment: Anyone? I help would be most appreciated